# What is the last names of these characters in Avatar?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

I was just wondering if these guys have surnames

- Zuko
- Ozai
- Korra
- Aang
- Katara
- Sokka

Answer if you know please. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that they don't have surnames, nor would those be a normal feature of the sort of pseudo-medieval oriental world that Avatar is set in.

Toph does have a sort-of surname ('Bei Fong') because she comes from a noble, albeit not royal family whereas Zuko, Ozai and Azula are true royalty and are thusly identified by their rank and station. Sokka and Kattara come from a peasant village and are therefore unlikely to have or even need a surname.
Aang has no surname but would probably identify himself by his status as a Buddhist monk

In many [Eastern cultures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_name#Historical_names), surnames are derived from either tribal affiliation or position

Therefore; full names would be

- **Fire Lord** Zuko
- **Fire Lord** Ozai
- Korra **of the Southern Water Tribe**
- Avatar Aang **[Thich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thich_Nhat_Hanh)**
- Katara **of the Southern Water Tribe**
- Sokka **of the Southern Water Tribe**

Comment: What's the basis for the Thich link or marking it as part of Aang's name? "Thich" seems to be a family name unrelated to Aang "identify[ing] himself by his status as a Buddhist monk", and [the Avatar wikia article on Aang](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Aang) mentions the word "Thich" nowhere. (Side note, I am not sure the Air Nomads would identify themselves as Buddhist monks anyway -- whilst they are certainly modelled on things in that vein, "Buddhist monks" have no sign of existing in the canon. Aang would be more likely to just identify himself as an Air Nomad.)

Comment: @Doppelgreener - Worthy of its own question. Are the air nomads Buddhists?

Answer (score 2):

### 404 Surnames not found.

Concurring with the [Avatar Wiki](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/), they do have alternative names, like nicknames or names in other regions. But they don't have surnames.

I don't know if there is other canon material which may present *"decayed surnames"*, but I'll guess unique names were enough for the author.

BTW: [Sokka](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Sokka) does have a really weird alternative name. How to obtain this in our world?

Comment: While Western names are often of the "given + sur" construction, many other cultures work differently. It's likely that Avatar-world naming conventions reflect a variety of East-Asian and East-Asian-adjacent cultures whose naming traditions Western audiences would be unfamiliar with. The information (if it was ever decided upon) was likely left out because it would take too much time to explain in comparison to its significance for the story.

Comment: Your answer lacks what I was looking for, but thanks for your contribution Trollwut.

Comment: Well ok, thought you were looking for surnames as they are for us. No problem. :)